# Is it possible showing another app screen on android?

Tags: android

I have `A(Main) app` and service `B app`

service B app is showing camera preview on another phone

I want to show `B app` screen in `A app`.

Is it possible?

Perhaps using the package name ?

this is a `activity_main.xml`  I want only showing another app screen in framelayout part

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="fghjfghj"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tv_process_info"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_process_info"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:hint="rtyurtyu"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp" />


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/another_app_view"></FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You want to mirror the screen of one device into another? That's likely 1) not possible 2) too broad to answer here

Comment: @cricket_007   update my question.   In xml , `id+another_app_view`   this part only showing another app screen

Comment: Your update doesn't really clarify anything. What you're asking is still too broad

Comment: um.. sorry. what do you want information ?

Comment: You're trying to display the screen of one device into another? There is no straight forward way to do that if it were possible

Comment: OK ...thanks cricket